# How to use PHP to fetch and decode JSON data?

Tags: php, json, curl, decode, file-get-contents

How can I get variables "price_usd" and "price_btc" from JSON url https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/? I wrote a script but nothing happens.

```
 <?php
$tick = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/'); 
$url = $tick;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$usd = $data[0]["price_usd"];
echo $usd;
?>
```

Comment: `print_r($data);`

Answer (score 3):

Your code use a file_get_contents twice, look at would be:

```
<?php
$tick = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/');
$url = $tick;
echo $url;
//$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($tick, TRUE);

$usd = $data[0]["price_usd"];
echo $usd;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/'); 
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data[0]->price_usd);

?>
```